# How to stop the div wrapping around the menu div

Tags: css, html

I have included the snippet of code below in jsbin, I want the main page div to sit next to the menubar div even when the resolution is too small for them both.

To clarify instead of the mainpage div wrapping around the menubar div, instead what I want when the browser screen is reduced horizontally is for the mainpage div to get as close to the menubar as it can, and then as the browser gets smaller horizontally to just start disappearing in the window.

http://jsbin.com/#/OkivEre/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I see in there:

- you have overflowing items in menubar
- you have set width 16% and 84%, but you also have borders that take space. Try using outline instead of border.